# How can i get to the child of div?

Tags: html, children

How can i get to the second span and take from here:

a)content of this span

b)tip of this span

How can i distinguish these spans without using id or something?

```
<div class="yea">
    <span tip="red">apple</span>
    <span tip="orange">orange</span>
    <span tip="yellow">banana</span>
    <span tip="brown">pineapple</span>
</div>
```

Comment: with CSS or JavaScript, what exactly you want to accomplish later? you should give more detail.
Also what did you try already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'CSS3 [**:nth-of-type()**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) Selector' to style your spans without using or having access to individual unique selectors.

*Example:*

```
span:nth-of-type(2) { // 2 grabs second instance
    background: red; // sample
}
```

You didn't add the jQuery or JavaScript tag to your question; but I believe this is what your looking for, for the other aspect of your question. [**.text();**](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

*Example:*

```
$('span:nth-of-type(2)').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

With CSS

```css
.yea /*class selector*/
{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.yea span[tip] /* selector for all spans with attribute 'tip' inside elements with class 'yea' */
{
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 70px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
span[tip]:first-child
{
  color: red;
}
span[tip]:last-child
{
  color: brown;
}
span[tip]:nth-child(2)
{
  background: darkgreen;
  color: orange;
}
span[tip]:nth-child(3)
{
  background: blue;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="yea">
    <span tip="red">apple</span>
    <span tip="orange">orange</span>
    <span tip="yellow">banana</span>
    <span tip="brown">pineapple</span>
</div>
```

more you find on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery**

to get content of the second span:

```
$( "div span:nth-child(2)" )
```

to get the tip of the same span

```
var tip = $( "span:nth-child(2)" ).attr( "tip" );
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the second span among a group of spans you can make use of `nth-child(2)` or `nth-of-type(2)`. To access the content and attribute you will have to use JavaScript preferable jQuery,

To access the content

```
$(".yea span:nth-of-type(2)').text();
```

To access the attribute `tip`

```
 $(".yea span:nth-of-type(2)').attr('tip');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple solution in pure JavaScript:

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('yea')[0].children[1],
    txt = el.textContent,
    tip = el.getAttribute('data-tip');

console.log(txt, tip);
```

```html
<div class="yea">
  <span data-tip="red">apple</span>
  <span data-tip="orange">orange</span>
  <span data-tip="yellow">banana</span>
  <span data-tip="brown">pineapple</span>
</div>
```

To select the second `span`, you could also use:

```
// getElementsByTagName
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('yea')[0].getElementsByTagName('span')[1];

// querySelector
var el = document.querySelector('.yea > span[data-tip="orange"]');
```

By the way, `tip` is not a valid HTML attribute. You should replace it with `data-tip`.